# Layout Specfic Keybinds in Xmonad/Dwm

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmonad

Does anyone know if its possible to have a different set of keybinds for different layouts.

For instance, in Tall mode, i would like h and l to switch between the master and stack, with k and l moving up and down the stack.

Then in Mirror Tall mode, i would like the operations switched, k,l switching between master and stack with h and l moving left and right through the stack.

Obivously im trying to emulate vim-like movement.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think so, you could hack at XMonad core to try and get something happening but I don't think you can do that by default. I could be wrong though which is why this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html (or maybe something better) to detect the layout and bind key to function which will decide based on layout in a way like this:

```
  ( ( modMask, xK_k ), act )
  -- ...
where
  act = do
    layout <- detectLayout -- not sure how to do this now
    if layout == "Tall" then act1 else act2
```

(Seems that I come way too late, maybe someone will use this eventually.)